# How do I divide a tensor into NXN block and reconstruct the first from these blocks again?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a tensor with shape (1,32,32) that the first index in shape shows the number of channels and my images are gray. now I need to divide this tensor into 8x8 blocks and do some processes on each block like DCT and after changes, replace these new blocks with the previous one. we have `mattocell` and `celltomat` in Matlab, but in keras, I do not know how can I do this? could you please tell your suggestions in Keras? Thank you.

I used this code:

```
def slicAndJpeg(img):
    for i in range (int(img.shape[1].value/8)):
        for j in range(int(img.shape[2].value/8)):
            temp=img[:,i*8:i*8+8,j*8:j*8+8]
            tempb=K.zeros((8,8))
            DCT(temp,tempb)
```

but I do not know it is true or not?! could you please tell me it is possible to use the above code for tensors in keras? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the before mentioned code and it works. based on my experiments we can do this by for loops, but if somebody has a better suggestion please put it here.

```
 def slicAndJpeg(img):
        for i in range (int(img.shape[1].value/8)):
            for j in range(int(img.shape[2].value/8)):
                temp=img[:,i*8:i*8+8,j*8:j*8+8]
                tempb=K.zeros((8,8))
                DCT(temp,tempb)
```